# FFmpeg sdl output in android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, sdl-2

I try to execute the next command

```
-i $inputFilePath -filter_complex \"realtime,scale=iw/2:-1,negate,format=yuv420p\" -f sdl2 -
```

with [mobile-ffmpeg](https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg) on android and get the next error

```
mobile-ffmpeg: [sdl,sdl2 @ 0xbf1d9600] Unable to initialize SDL: Application didn't initialize properly, did you include SDL_main.h in the file containing your main() function?
```

As far as I understand I need to create `SDL_Activity` or something similar to display video, am I right? Please explain if I'm wrong otherwise help me.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @iamkdblue unfortunatelly no